# RabbitMQ startup error in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I got an error in my code when I started `SpringBootApplication` after a month later.
It was working before but now I get error of: **HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration**

1. rabbitMQ instance is working in my VM
2. that is reachable from SpringBoot instance.
3. added `health.rabbit.enabled=false` into `application.properties`

Does somebody know about what kind of error is this?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthAggregator org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration.healthAggregator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at demo.SpringDemoApplication.main(SpringDemoApplication.java:13) [bin/:na]
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.2.3.RELEASE'
}
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
 }
 dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
baseName = 'spring-demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

// web
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
// batch
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch")

// mongo
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver")

// lombok
compile("org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.4")

// template change to use my thymleaf
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
compile('org.unbescape:unbescape:1.1.1.RELEASE');
//compile('net.sourceforge.nekohtml:nekohtml:1.9.22')

//  session
compile("org.springframework.session:spring-session:1.0.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis:1.2.4.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis:1.0.1.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:1.4.1.RELEASE")
compile("redis.clients:jedis:2.4.1")

//  face book
compile("org.springframework.social:spring-social-facebook")

//  standford
compile('edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-parser:3.5.2')
compile('edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.5.2')
compile('edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:3.5.2:models')
compile('edu.washington.cs.knowitall.stanford-corenlp:stanford-parse-models:1.3.2')

//  JMS
compile('org.springframework:spring-jms:4.2.2.RELEASE')
compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.12.1')

// Rabbit MQ with JMS
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp")

//  Kuromoji
compile("org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:5.5.0")
compile("org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-kuromoji:5.5.0")

//  mahout
compile("org.apache.mahout:mahout-core:0.9")

//  aws
//compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:1.0.1.RELEASE')
//compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:1.0.1.RELEASE')
//compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-autoconfigure:1.0.1.RELEASE')

//  security
//compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

//  thymeleaf
// for this time , this referes local project
// org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:2.1.4.RELEASE
//compile('ognl:ognl:3.0.8');
//compile('org.unbescape:unbescape:1.1.0.RELEASE')
//compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:1.2.3.RELEASE');
//compile('nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect:1.2.7');
/*compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"){
    // this setting is for the local debugging thymeleaf
    exclude group: 'org.thymeleaf', module: 'thymeleaf-spring4'
    exclude group: 'org.thymeleaf', module: 'thymeleaf'
}*/

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.3.3.RELEASE');
compile('com.h2database:h2:1.4.191');


testCompile("junit:junit")

}

configurations {
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

eclipse {
classpath {
     containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
     containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
}
}

springBoot {
mainClass = "demo.SpringDemoApplication"
}
```

**My Configuration of Rabbit**

```
package demo.configs;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

public class RabbitMQConfig {

@Bean
CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(){
    CachingConnectionFactory rabicon = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    //amqp.connect('amqp://admin:admin@192.168.3.3:5672/',
    //rabicon.setHost("192.168.3.3");
    rabicon.setHost(Const.Rabbit_Host);
    rabicon.setUsername(Const.Rabbit_User);
    rabicon.setPassword(Const.Rabbit_Pass);
    rabicon.setPort(5672);
    return rabicon;
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessage(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(Const.RabbitMQMessageQue);
    //container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store an invalid type into some array? Your exception cause is `ArrayStoreException`!

Comment: What do you have in your pom.xml file?